# Generate real time audio recorder plot

Tags: ios, swift, plot, avaudiorecorder

I recorder audio using `AVAudioRecorder` in Swift.

Now I want to generate a Real time wave plot from audio that I'm recording from microphone.

On github I found something but its not realtime but only from an file audio just saved.

Answer (score 1):

For displaying real-time audio input on iOS, you might want to use the RemoteIO Audio Unit for a lower latency, closer to real-time, instead of the AVAudioRecorder API.

I have posted a GitHub Gist demonstrating drawing a spectrum from Audio Unit microphone input (using the iOS Metal API for low latency graphics as well) here: https://gist.github.com/hotpaw2/f108a3c785c7287293d7e1e81390c20b